# DateTime.now in Elixir and Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to get the current date-time stamp in Phoenix/Elixir without a third-party library. Or simply, I want something like `DateTime.now()`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ecto has [`Ecto.DateTime.utc/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.DateTime.html#utc/1) to get the current time in UTC:

```
iex(1)> Ecto.DateTime.utc
#Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-05 13:30:04>
iex(2)> Ecto.DateTime.utc(:usec) # include microseconds
#Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-05 13:30:18.367318>
```

If you want the current time in the local system's timezone, you can do:

```
Ecto.DateTime.from_erl(:erlang.localtime)
```

Answer (score 15):

As of Ecto 3, `Ecto.Date`, `Ecto.Time` and `Ecto.DateTime` no longer exist, as stated [here.](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2018/10/a-sneak-peek-at-ecto-3-0-breaking-changes/)

However, Elixir now ships with [DateTime](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#content), [Date](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Date.html#content) and [NaiveDateTime](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#content), which should be used.

```
iex(1)> DateTime.utc_now
#DateTime<2019-01-14 12:05:52.271492Z>
```